# XSLT geom in xml to postgres geometry

Tags: xml, postgresql, xslt, geometry

I do import from XML to Postgres helpfull XSLT.
Data includes geometry. Like this:

```
<PSK ID="150" COLUMN1="0" COLUMN2="NAME" etc...>
  <GEOMETRY>
    <MP>
      <P>
        <L>
          <B S="1138651.418423$821451.456086"/>
          <B S="1138654.369616$821413.617474"/>
          <B S="1138678.358112$821407.805787"/>
          <B S="1138666.451862$821433.734954"/>
          <B S="1138660.366446$821456.224537"/>
          <B S="1138651.418423$821451.456086"/>
         </L>
       </P>
       <P>
         <L>
           <B S="1138237.562279$821893.845370"/>
           <B S="1138241.531029$821884.849537"/>
           <B S="1138246.293215$821878.627972"/>
           <B S="1138257.935196$821863.418287"/>
           <B S="1138264.814362$821835.901620"/>
           <B S="1138267.781570$821808.009850"/>
           <B S="1138268.783112$821798.595370"/>
           <B S="1138279.631029$821771.872454"/>
           <B S="1138293.124779$821753.351621"/>
           <B S="1138307.147696$821751.234954"/>
           <B S="1138302.893801$821783.629991"/>
           <B S="1138300.268528$821803.622454"/>
           <B S="1138290.478945$821827.699537"/>
           <B S="1138280.424778$821851.512037"/>
           <B S="1138255.168055$821899.238258"/>
           <B S="1138245.235195$821935.914121"/>
           <B S="1138237.562279$821949.407870"/>
           <B S="1138247.087278$821956.022453"/>
           <B S="1138243.647696$821968.457870"/>
           <B S="1138247.087278$821972.162037"/>
           <B S="1138245.764362$821980.364120"/>
           <B S="1138249.203945$821984.332870"/>
           <B S="1138241.531029$822005.234954"/>
           <B S="1138250.791445$822012.643287"/>
           <B S="1138243.912279$822039.366203"/>
           <B S="1138214.278946$822027.195371"/>
           <B S="1138207.135195$822020.580787"/>
           <B S="1138198.668530$822040.953704"/>
           <B S="1138185.968529$822057.357870"/>
           <B S="1138186.497696$822017.934954"/>
           <B S="1138193.641445$821993.593287"/>
           <B S="1138196.309929$821984.698344"/>
           <B S="1138198.403946$821977.718287"/>
           <B S="1138210.788458$821954.279473"/>
           <B S="1138237.562279$821893.845370"/>
         </L>
       </P>
     </MP>
  </GEOMETRY>
```

Tag `<PSK>` is main entity.

I don't know, How I write XSLT format for this geometry.
I try to explain this geometry.

```
<MP> is ALL Multipolygon
<P> is a Polygon
<L> is simple linie with which the polygon is composed
<B> is point in polygon.
```

Now my XSLT file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date"    
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:n="http://www.uhul.cz/">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="DATAISLH">           
  <xsl:for-each select="PATH/TO/ARRAY/IN/XML/PSK">  
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>  
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>       
    .
    .
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>     
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I want insert geometry to db, but I don't know, how I insert tag  with XSLT.
Idealy, When It will be in WKT (Wll-Known text) format like this:
There is full example of copy

```
COPY 150 0 name MULTIPOLYGON(...)
```

Example Multipolygon

```
MULTIPOLYGON(
(
  (
    -769664.74 -1182873.54,
    -769662.74 -1182923.54,
    -769649.69 -1182949.35,
    -769619.73 -1182943.54,
    -769615.73 -1182903.54,
    -769617.73 -1182869.54,
    -769664.74 -1182873.54
  )
),
  (
    (
      -769702.45 -1182871.97,
      -769691.7 -1182816.71,
      -769655.44 -1182852.46,
      -769702.45 -1182871.97
    )
  )
)
```

I should save to db like text and next step I should make replace $ to space and other steps. But I think, It doesn't save like WKT.

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Before you write any XSLT you need to know what output you want. Can you edit your question to show the output you expect in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is corrent remark, thnak you, I did it.

Comment: Ideally, your output should correspond directly to the input you have shown in the question. It might help if you showed a more detailed input XML. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve